Se la he dejado = Ethical Dativ?
I found this sentence in a short story for Spanish learners and I wonder about it:
–¡Esa chaqueta es mía! Se la he dejado a Sergio para estos días. ¡Dios mío, es él! –grita Juan.
Is the "se" an ethical dativ or what other gramatical type of word is this?

There are no datives in Spanish and English. Latin and Greek have datives, nominatives, ablatives etc. "se" there is a pronoun, used reflexively in Spanish use them: me, te, se, etc. https://espanol.lingolia.com/en/grammar/verbs/reflexive-verbs#:~:text=What%20is%20a%20reflexive%20verb,reflexive%20verbs%20end%20in%20%2Dse.&text=The%20key%20thing%20about%20reflexive,are%20one%20and%20the%20same.

@Lambie All Romance languages have kept some pronoun declensions although not necessarily reported as such by some grammars. Not to mention the Saxon genitive (apostrophe + s), this is also true with English which have three or four cases:  Nominative, genitive, dative, and accusative = dative, e.g.: he, his, him, him; French: Je, mien, moi, me, Spanish: yo, mí, me, me.  Note also that se is not a reflexive pronoun in the OP sentence because it doesn't represent the subject of the verb.

@Gavatx Declined languages change the endings of their nouns. English and Spanish do not have that at all except to add s or es in the plural. The Saxon genitive is just a way to describe the possessive of apostrophe s and does not describe a form in a declined language. It is just an origin. And anyway, this question has already been answered: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/14883/when-to-use-ethical-datives-in-spanish#:~:text=Ethical%20datives%20are%20clitics%20(or,gonna%20buy%20me%20some%20shoes.

@Lambie Of course, everyone would agree English and Spanish do not decline their nouns. However, the OP is referring to a pronoun and many pronouns are still declined in most European languages regardless of how grammars might call these variations.

This question is not a duplicate because the other one (that I already mentioned in my reply) only refers to ethical datives while that one asks about the grammatical type of se, which is not an ethical dative but a dativo benefactivo.

It is a dative of interest as the pronoun se (technically le = a él = 'to him', not a reflexive pronoun) represent the person that benefit from the action (Sergio). As this pronoun is redundant (he dejado la chaqueta a Sergio ➔ la he dejado a Sergio would be sufficient), it is close to an aspectual dative but doesn't fully match its definition because the pronoun doesn't correspond to the subject.
The following sentence which is equally idiomatic contains an aspectual dative:

Me la he dejado a Sergio para estos días.

As a reference, here are a RAE introduction about declensions and a definition of the interest and ethical datives in the context of the Spanish language:

Por oposición a los sustantivos, el paradigma de los pronombres personales es el único que ha mantenido en español la distinción morfológica de caso [...]
Source: RAE caso
Se llama tradicionalmente dativo de interés (también dativo benefactivo o malefactivo) al que hace referencia al individuo que resulta beneficiado o perjudicado por la acción verbal (Le hicieron un vestido nuevo; Me han cortado el gas).
[...]
Se denomina dativo ético al pronombre átono no reflexivo que se
refiere al individuo implicado afectivamente por la acción que denota
el predicado (No me vaya a llorar ahora). En la tradición, este dativo
solía cubrir también los usos del hoy llamado dativo aspectual, que
posee igualmente carácter enfático. Sin embargo, este último dativo
concuerda en número y persona con el sujeto oracional, como Me leí (o
bien te leíste, se leyó, etc.) todo el diario.
Source: RAE dativo

While noun case declensions have disappeared from English and most Romance languages, declensions still exist with all of them as far as pronouns are concerned.
e.g. (1st and 3rd person masc. singular):



Language
Nominative
Accusative
Dative
Genitive




Spanish
yo / él
me / le
(a) mí/me / (a) él/le
(de) mí/mío / (de) él/suyo


English
I / he
me / him
me / him
mine / his


German1
ich / er
mich / ihn
mir / ihm
meiner / seiner


French
je / il
me / le
moi / lui
le mien / sien



1German declines nouns too.
See also When to use "ethical datives" in Spanish
